# Replace LOG(fatal) by an exception

Tags: c++, glog

I'm currently using caffe but I'm facing a problem. Sometime the library call `LOG(FATAL)` but I would like to raise an exception and catch it.

I have tried to do my own class defined as below:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class FatalException
{
private:
  std::stringstream _ss;
public:
  template<typename T>
  std::ostream& operator<<(const T& obj){
    _ss << obj;
    return _ss;
  }
  ~FatalException(){
    throw std::runtime_error(_ss.str().c_str());
  }
};
```

The problem is that when I'm doing some testing such as

```
int main() {
    try {
    FatalException() << "test";
    }
    catch(...) {
    std::cout << "here" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

the exception is thrown after the `try` scope

Do you have any hints? 
Should I overload a stream class and throw an exception when the stream is flushed?

Comment: I'm not experienced with [tag:caffe] (even if my avatar might imply that), but what's `LOG(FATAL)` actually? Is it a macro called from the library internally? Can you recompile that library and redefine the macro?

Comment: It's actually from google glog,  "Logging a FATAL message terminates the program (after the message is logged)"

Comment: I'm afraid that's the intended behavior there, and you're not supposed to somehow hook or catch it yourself, but you should rather fix the source of the error. But well, as mentioned I'm not an expert about that specific environment.

Comment: I had to catch exceptions as well. I could not make it work with glog although they have "User-defined Failure Functions". So I had to replace glog with a stream class. In my point of view, it is the best option. Unfortunately I cannot make the code public.